# Cargar un arbol desde archivo

Tags: python

Tengo un árbol con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual tengo almacenado en un fichero, con el siguiente contenido:

> 1 - 2 3 4 * 2 - 5 6 7 * 5 - 11 12 13 14 * 11 - * 12 - * 13 - * 14 - * 6 - * 7 - * 3 - * 4 - 8 9 10 * 8 - 15 16 * 15 - * 16 - * 9 - * 10 - *

La estructura es la siguiente:

- "*****" : separa "familias de nodos" es decir estructuras compuestas de un padre y sus hijos.
- "**- ***" : indica que un nodo no tiene hijos.
- "**-**" : indica los hijos de un nodo.

A continuación especifico su implementación en Python:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
```

Y el código para generar el árbol presentado:

```
#A continuación defino todos los nodos
a = node(1)
b = node(2)
c = node(3)
d = node(4)
e = node(5)
f = node(6)
g = node(7)
h = node(8)
i = node(9)
j = node(10)
k = node(11)
l = node(12)
ll = node(13)
m = node(14)
n = node(15)
o = node(16)
# A continuación defino las relaciones de parentesco
a.add_child(b)
a.add_child(c)
a.add_child(d)
b.add_child(e)
b.add_child(f)
b.add_child(g)
d.add_child(h)
d.add_child(i)
d.add_child(j)
h.add_child(n)
h.add_child(o)
e.add_child(k)
e.add_child(l)
e.add_child(ll)
e.add_child(m)
```

Tengo funciones que me recorren el árbol implementado en python y me lo guardan en un fichero en el formato señalado al principio de este post. 
Pero ahora, lo que quiero hacer es cargarlo de ese formato en un programa, y para ello tengo que usar el código de la clase nodo presentado arriba.
A continuación escribo el código que estoy desarrollando:

```
#1. Genero todos los nodos
#1.2 Reduzco la cadena a elementos que no se repitan
cadena2 = list(set(cadena.split()))
#print(cadena2)
#1.3 Elimino de la cadena los símbolos '*' y '-'
cadena2.remove("*")
cadena2.remove("-")
#print(cadena2)
#1.4 Genero todos los nodos
listanodos = []
i = 0
while i < len(cadena2):
    listanodos = listanodos + [node(cadena2[i])]
    i = i + 1
#2 Vinculo los nodos hijos a los padres
# ¿Cómo lo hago?
```

Ya que consigo generar los nodos, guardándolos en una lista, ahora solo me falta crear relaciones de parentesco entre ellos, intuyo que hay que ir recorriendo`cadena` para ello.

Comment: La solución simple pasa por usar `str.split` junto a un casting a `int`. Deberías considerar tener una clase `Árbol` que represente al árbol en si y que permita almacenar sus nodos en un atributo, tal y como lo tienes (al menos lo que muestras) tendrías que crear variables de forma dinámica para cargar los nodos, lo cual no es recomendable generalmente. Si tienes esta clase, deberías mostrarla ya que es necesaria para reconstruir el árbol desde el fichero. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla: Si, he pensado algo parecido a lo que me comentas, lo de usar 'str.split'. Ahora edito la pregunta y añado más información.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como has intentado, `str.split` es una forma simple de hacer lo que deseas (expresiones regulares podría ser otra opción). No obstante, primero debes separar cada nodo (pareja padre-hijos) mediante `split('*')`, posteriormente se debe iterar sobre cada nodo para separar el padre de los hijos mediante split('-') y por último usar `split(' ')` sobre los hijos.

Usar un diccionario para almacenar cada identificador del nodo (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) con la instancia correspondiente de la clase puede ser una forma sencilla de resolver el problema:

```
cad = ('1 - 2 3 4 * 2 - 5 6 7 * 5 - 11 12 13 14 * 11 - * '
       '12 - * 13 - * 14 - * 6 - * 7 - * 3 - * 4 - 8 9 10 * '
       '8 - 15 16 * 15 - * 16 - * 9 - * 10 - *')

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)


nodes = [n.split('-') for n in cad.split('*')][:-1]
nodes = {int(parent): [int(child) for child in children.split()]
                                      for parent, children in nodes}
nodes_instances = {n: Node(n) for n in nodes}

for parent, children in nodes.items():
    for child in children:
        nodes_instances[parent].add_child(nodes_instances[child])

listanodos = nodes_instances.values()
```

La clave está en:

```
nodes = {int(parent): [int(child) for child in children.split()]
                                      for parent, children in nodes}
```

Esto nos retorna un diccionario en el que cada clave es el identificador de un nodo y el valor una lista con los identificadores de sus hijos. En este ejemplo nos retorna:

```
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 7], 5: [11, 12, 13, 14], 11: [], 12: [],13: [], 14: [],
 6: [], 7: [], 3: [], 4: [8, 9, 10], 8: [15, 16],15: [], 16: [], 9: [], 10: []}
```

Ahora podemos usar las claves del diccionario para instanciar cada nodo y almacenarlo en otro diccionario:

```
nodes_instances = {n: Node(n) for n in nodes}
```

para posteriormente poder ir añadiendo cada instancia de los nodos hijos a las instancias de sus respectivos padres en el `for`.

La salida es una lista con los nodos instanciados igual que haces originalmente:

```
>>> for n in listanodos:
>>>    print('{:<2} ---> {}'.format(n.data,
           (', '.join(str(c.data) for c in n.children) if n.children else None)))

1  ---> 2, 3, 4
2  ---> 5, 6, 7
5  ---> 11, 12, 13, 14
11 ---> None
12 ---> None
13 ---> None
14 ---> None
6  ---> None
7  ---> None
3  ---> None
4  ---> 8, 9, 10
8  ---> 15, 16
15 ---> None
16 ---> None
9  ---> None
10 ---> None
```

> **Nota:** He renombrado la clase `nodo` para que empiece con mayúscula según las convenciones y  PEP-8.